# Databricks - How can we use a single common PAT Token access for multiple databricks Workspaces which is under the same admin databricks account

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to know how its possible to use single PAT token to access multiple datarbicks workspaces

I referred lot of api documentation, workspace, admin authorization documentation

Answer (score 1):

> No, it's not possible - personal access token (PAT) is bound to a specific user/service principal in the specific workspace, it's unique.

But on Azure Databricks it's better to use Azure Active Directory (AAD) tokens instead of PATs - they are more secure, plus you can use the same AAD token for multiple workspaces to which you have access. You can read more about different ways of generating AAD tokens in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/).